# Camera rotating around the object in a regular way with python blender

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, camera

I want a camera that rotates regularly around the object I have taken with the blender package in python, and I want to take the image of the three-dimensional object from certain angles at the time of this rotation and render it, I wrote a code in this way, but the rotation angle of the camera is not very healthy. Also, according to the size of the object I take, the object does not appear in the images I take from some angles. exactly what I want is to be able to do this process in a stable way, let the object be fixed in the middle and draw a flat circle around the camera and take an image. can you help me with this?

```
def rotate(point, angle_degrees, axis=(0, 1, 0)):
theta_degrees = angle_degrees
theta_radians = math.radians(theta_degrees)
rotate_point = np.dot(rotation_matrix(axis, theta_radians), point)

return rotate_point


def fit_camera_to_object(camera, obj):
# Calculate the bounding box of the object
bbox = [obj.matrix_world @ v.co for v in obj.data.vertices]
min_x = min(bbox, key=lambda v: v.x).x
max_x = max(bbox, key=lambda v: v.x).x
min_y = min(bbox, key=lambda v: v.y).y
max_y = max(bbox, key=lambda v: v.y).y
min_z = min(bbox, key=lambda v: v.z).z
max_z = max(bbox, key=lambda v: v.z).z

# Calculate the center of the bounding box
center_x = (max_x + min_x) / 2
center_y = (max_y + min_y) / 2
center_z = (max_z + min_z) / 2

# Calculate the distance from the camera to fit the object in view
distance_to_fit = max(max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y, max_z - min_z) * 3

# Set the camera location and rotation
camera.location = (center_x - distance_to_fit, center_y, center_z + distance_to_fit)
camera.rotation_euler = (math.radians(90), 0, math.radians(45))  # Adjust rotation as 
needed

# Adjust camera height to fit the entire object
camera.location.z = max_z + distance_to_fit  # You may need to fine-tune this


def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
axis = np.asarray(axis)
axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac)],
             [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab)],
             [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc]])


def rotate_camera_around_object(angle, obj, axis=(0, 0, 1)):
Rotate camera around the specified object
cam_location = cam.location - obj.location
rotated_cam_location = rotate(cam_location, angle, axis)
cam.location = rotated_cam_location + obj.location



# Delete default cube
cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
bpy.data.objects.remove(cube)


# İmport stl
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath="C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\stlfile\\a.stl")
stl = bpy.context.active_object
# Example: Set the location of the object
stl.location = (0, 0, 0)  # Adjust the location as needed


light_data = bpy.data.lights.new('light', type='SUN')

light = bpy.data.objects.new('light', light_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light)
light.location = (3, -4, 5)
light.data.energy = 200.0

# create camera
cam_data = bpy.data.cameras.new('camera')
cam = bpy.data.objects.new('camera', cam_data)


# Assuming 'stl' is your object and 'cam' is your camera
fit_camera_to_object(cam, stl)


constraint = cam.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
constraint.target = stl


bpy.context.collection.objects.link(cam)

# create material
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='Material')
mat.use_nodes = True
mat_nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
mat_links = mat.node_tree.links

stl.data.materials.append(mat)


# metallic
mat_nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Metallic'].default_value = 1.0
mat_nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (
0.005634391214698553, 0.01852927729487419, 0.8000000715255737, 0.01852927729487419)
mat_nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Roughness'].default_value = 0.167


# Set the world background color (change to your desired color)
bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes["Background"].inputs[0].default_value = (1, 1, 
1, 1)  # White background

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.camera = cam
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'


for angle in range(0, 360, 10):
try:
rotate_camera_around_object(10, stl)

# Set the filepath to the same folder for each angle
scene.render.filepath = f'C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\blend\\blender_{angle}.png'
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)  # Render and save image
except Exception as e:
print(f"Error: {e}")
```

and the result is an off-centred object and a half visible object
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Have you checked if your object's origin is correct? 
if yes, wouldn't it be easier to set a "Track To" constraint to the camera? So it will have your object in field of view, and you will avoid a lot of computation

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes the object looks correct when I view it. and I use the method you mentioned in this part of my code.
constraint = cam.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
constraint.target = stl